# How to get connection string which is connected right now

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, connection-string

How can i get the connection string which is right now connected to the database?

I can get all the connection strings but how can i get which one is connected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can by two way. First by .NET `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` object which connect to sql by this object. Second use self Sql Server to tell you what is the current connection string, if you use from sql server database!

Answer (score 0):

For connections that are not using the default connection e.g. .\SQLEXPRESS the following will give you the connections stored in app.config and a method to track the connection. In the form example I am using ms-access but this will work with sql-server also.

**Edit**: [here is a fully function code example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Managing-connection-2cf7ceaa) on Microsoft's code sample web sute I just created.

Supporting classes

```
Public Class ConfigItem
    Public Property Data As System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings
    Public Property Index As Integer
End Class
Public Class ConnectionInfo
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ConnectionString As String
    Public Property Index As Integer
End Class
```

Worker class to get connection names, index and connection string

```
Imports System.Configuration
''' <summary>
''' Must add a reference to System.Configuration
''' to this project.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class ProjectConnections
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Storage for connections
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property Items As New List(Of ConnectionInfo)
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Used to remember the current connection
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property CurrentConnectionIndex As Integer

    Private RemoveThis As String = ""
    Public Sub New()
        ' look at parent assembly as this class is in a class project used by a 
        ' forms project
        RemoveThis = Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.GetName.Name & ".My.MySettings."
        ' get connection data into the Items propery of this class
        GetInformation()
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Traverse through connection strings in app.config, exclude local sql-server connection
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' tested with ms-access, sql-server attached and server based
    ''' </remarks>
    Private Sub GetInformation()
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Cast(Of ConnectionStringSettings)().Select(
            Function(item, index) New ConfigItem With {.Data = item, .Index = index}).ToList _
            .ForEach(
                Sub(ConfigItem)
                    If ConfigItem.Data.Name.Contains(".") Then
                        Items.Add(
                            New ConnectionInfo With
                                {
                                    .Name = ConfigItem.Data.Name.Replace(RemoveThis, ""),
                                    .ConnectionString = ConfigItem.Data.ConnectionString,
                                    .Index = ConfigItem.Index
                                })
                    End If
                End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form utilizing the classes above. In this case there are two connections stored in app.config. The worker class is instantiated at form level so we can use it to track the current connection string. Optionally we could localize the class and use a private integer variable to remember the current connection. In form load, I am choosing which connection to use rather than the default, stored the index for that connection in the worker class instance, display connection string names in a ComboBox and exposing all information in a DataGridView. Pressing a button, we change the connection at runtime while a second button shows the underlying connection string.

Note the import statement, I placed the worker class into a class project so the form project must have a reference to it then followed by the import statement.

```
Imports ConfigurationLibrary

Public Class Form1
    Private connections As ProjectConnections = New ProjectConnections()
    Private Sub CustomersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles CustomersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

        Me.Validate()
        Me.CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' here I am loading a connection other than the default
        CustomersTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = connections.Items(1).ConnectionString
        ' for keeping track later as in cmdGetConnection.Click
        connections.CurrentConnectionIndex = 1
        Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Customers)
        cboConnections.DataSource = connections.Items
        cboConnections.DisplayMember = "Name"
        cboConnections.SelectedIndex = 1

        dgvInformation.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        dgvInformation.DataSource = connections.Items
        CustomersDataGridView.ExpandColumns()
        dgvInformation.ExpandColumns()
    End Sub
    Private Sub cmdSetConnection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSetConnection.Click
        Dim OrdinalIndex As Integer = CType(cboConnections.SelectedItem, ConnectionInfo).Index - 1
        CustomersTableAdapter.Connection.Close()
        CustomersTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = connections.Items(OrdinalIndex).ConnectionString
        CustomersTableAdapter.Connection.Open()
        CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Customers)
        cboConnections.SelectedIndex = OrdinalIndex
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdGetConnection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGetConnection.Click
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.AppendLine(cboConnections.Text)
        sb.AppendLine(connections.Items(connections.CurrentConnectionIndex).ConnectionString)

        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Screenshot
[image]